# Unexpected character(<) position 0 Java

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have a small problem with my json parser

When i try to parse a string i get this exception:

```
Unexpected character (<) at position 0
```

But i dont see where the problem is. This is the code that i made:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(response);
            System.out.println(obj);

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            // loop the string
            //id = (String) jsonObject.get("id");
            voornaam = (String) jsonObject.get("voornaam");
            achternaam = (String) jsonObject.get("achternaam");

            _voornaamTxtField.setText(voornaam);
            _achternaamTxtField.setText(achternaam);

        } catch (ParseException pex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ParseException",
                    "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println(pex);
        } catch (NullPointerException npex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NullpointerException",
                    "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Can someone explain to me what i am doeing to cause the exception

Comment: Can you add the content of response please?

Comment: What is in the input data? I guess you are trying to read XML as JSON.

Comment: you most probably try to parse something with unescaped chracters. Seeing the JSON would be more usefull than seeing the code in that case I guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON: "Unexpected character (<) at position 0"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070380/json-unexpected-character-at-position-0)

Comment: @stuXnet how is this an duplicate of that?

Comment: You are trying to parse data that is not a valid json.

Comment: try you content validity at http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response string is not a JSON. Most probably it is an XML.
If your response is a response for a http call, you need to specify content type to be "application/json", then may be service will return you a JSON string, if service supports that.